# OnPostExecute Method doesn't get called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

My AsyncTask DoInBachground and OnPreExecute method is calling and working but Onpostexecute doesnt get called .

```
public class Push_notification_RecyclerView extends Fragment {
 intialise();
            new DBNotificationAsyncTask(myDBHelper).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        initialiseListeners();
        return view;
    }

    public void intialise() {
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        adapter = new PushNotificationAdapter(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(getContext());
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
        toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
    }

    private void initialiseListeners() {
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }



    private class DBNotificationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        MyDBHelper myDBHelper;

        public DBNotificationAsyncTask(MyDBHelper myDBHelper) {
            super();
            this.myDBHelper = myDBHelper;
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void notelist) {
            adapter.addapplication(notificationList());
            super.onPostExecute(notelist);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            adapter.clearApplications();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }


    public ArrayList<String> notificationList(){
        notelist = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = myDBHelper.getAllnotification();
            int c = cursor.getCount();
                if (c>0) {
                if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String message = myDBHelper.getNotificationMessageColumn(cursor) + myDBHelper.getNotificationMessageColumn(cursor);
                    notelist.add(message);
//                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }else{
                    notelist.add("No Data");
                }

            cursor.close();
            myDBHelper.close();

        return notelist;
    }
}
```

**After executing background and onpre mehtod , my async straight jumped to Adapter getItemcount method which return 0. Hence , no item shows in recyclerview**

**Adapter.class**

```
public class PushNotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PushNotificationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> notifyList = new ArrayList<>();
    public PushNotificationAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addapplication(ArrayList<String> notifyList){
        this.notifyList=notifyList;
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, notifyList.size() - 1);

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.push_notify_single_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(notifyList.get(position));



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notifyList.size();
    }

    public void clearApplications() {
        int size = this.notifyList.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                notifyList.remove(0);
            }

            this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView ;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.push_textview);

        }
    }
}
```

> Please help me finding bug which not letting my OnPostExecute to be
>   called . Thanks in advance .

Comment: it seems there is no code in doInBackground !!!

Comment: @Nisarg    yes , because evrything i am doing is in PostExecute.Please check code , From PostExecute , method is calling .

Comment: " my async straight jumped to Adapter getItemcount method" What does that suppose to mean? If your onPostExecute is not called how can it trigger another method? At preExecute() you clear the adapter.Did you put a log in onPostExecute to verify that it's not called?

Comment: @MalithLakshan : no i have not checked it by putting log . But while debugging ,my control never goes to onpost and the method inside it never called so . I figure it out that there is an issue with OnPost